# Spring automatically injects method parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I've started to learn spring and I'm a bit confused about this:
If I create a spring @Controller or @RestController and then in the method I ask for different parameters, I've noticed that spring automatically populate those parameters even without having them declared as bean or component.

So on my project I've a Movie class (a simple POJO) and I need to have a singleton instance of RestTemplate too. The first approach was to declare the RestTemplate bean and then ask for it using the @Autowired and that's working fine. After that I've commented out that part of code and put the RestTemplate and Movie as parameters of my method and spring is automatically providing me those instances even though I don't have any bean declaration of them.

I thought spring leverages on bean declaration to do dependency injection so my question is why do I've to declare the bean and use @Autowired if spring already injects whatever I want inside the method? Does spring injects a singleton instance of these parameters? And is this okay to use or better to decalre the bean and go through @Autowired?

Below the classes:

This is my movie model:

```
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Movie {

    private String movieId;
    private String name;
    
}
```

This is my rest controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/catalog")
public class MovieCatalogController {
    
    //@Autowired
    //private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @RequestMapping("/{userId}")
    public List<Catalog> getCatalog(@PathVariable("userId") String userId, RestTemplate restTemplate, Movie movie){
        // todo
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

}
```

And the main spring boot application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MovieCatalogServiceApplication {
    
    //@Bean
    //public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
        //return new RestTemplate();
    //}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MovieCatalogServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Thank you

Comment: It doesn't inject into the method, it will actually create a new `RestTEmplate` and not use the one from the context. This is also specific to Spring MVC as it will construct objects it doesn't now and use them as model attributes and bind parameters from the request to it. What you should be doing is autowiring it in your class (and as you are using Spring Boot you don't need to define the `RestTemplate` as a bean as Spring Boot automatically provided one).

Comment: thanks for your reply Deinum. So this is not a DI case and it's a behaviour of spring mvc model object right?
For teh RestTemplate bean if I remove the bean definition it will give me an error:
"required a bean of type 'org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate' that could not be found."

Comment: This is indeed not a DI case but Spring MVC behavior. Regarding the error, that is weird, if you use Spring Boot (properly!) it will provide one.

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is called method injection. Any component can be injected as long as there is a single implementation (you can specify what implementation to use when this is not the case with profiles or with [@Qualifier annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire#1-autowiring-by-qualifier))

The number of instances of the class is dictated by the @scope. [Singleton is the default scope](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes) so you should be ok without needing to use your bean definition.

@autowired is a bit old by now but still has its uses. Although for basic injection [it is preferred to use constructor or method injection](https://www.baeldung.com/constructor-injection-in-spring#pros-and-cons).

I'm fairly new to Spring myself, so I might be wrong

Comment: No it isn't, Spring will actually create a new instance of the `RestTemplate` for this method and not use the one from the context.

Comment: thanks Demian for your reply. I think we have method injection only with setter but in this case my getCatalog method is part of my controller and it's asking for more params

Comment: @M.Deinum  can you clarify? Do you mean because its method injection or in general?
@Eddie why not just inject in in the constructor `MovieCatalogController(RestTemplate template) { this.template=template}`

Comment: What happens here is a feature of Spring MVC creating an instance of an class and using that as a model object. So it isn't DI but rather model object construction due to Spring MVC. Method injection is used in the `@Bean` annotated methods when you pass in 1 or more dependencies into that method.